# How to separate data columns by year using basic SQL (bigquery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a visualization using `bigquery` and `chartio`. I want to display traffic volumes by day for each year to compare on one viz, to help identify seasonality.

I can break down the traffic by having a single column for traffic and another column for month and one for year, but this data structure doesn't work when I try to build the viz is `chartio`.

So what I am trying to do is to set a column for each year, where I have the traffic numbers set out by month. I am not sure of the way to do this, I know I probably need a union or a join here.

The code below combines the values, but doesn't get what I want.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS month,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year,
  SUM(CAST(traffic AS INT64)) AS traffic
FROM
  data.source
GROUP BY month, year
```

This is the output I get:

```
month   year    traffic
1   2017    11991865
3   2019    3482067
8   2017    21345567
6   2016    85207567
3   2018    22010756
```

What I want is:

```
month   traffic_2016    traffic_2017
1   233391865   11991865
2   1123465     3482067
3   11996545    21345567
4   119916655   85207567
5   34571865    22010756
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using IF-ELSE / CASE WHEN statement with GROUP BY

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS month,
  SUM(IF(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = 2016, CAST(traffic AS INT64), 0) AS traffic_2016,
  SUM(IF(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = 2017, CAST(traffic AS INT64), 0) AS traffic_2017,
FROM
  data.source
GROUP BY month
```

Simply with Join

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(SELECT
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS month,
  SUM(CAST(traffic AS INT64)) AS traffic_2016
FROM
  data.source
WHERE
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = 2016
GROUP BY month)
JOIN
(SELECT
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS month,
  SUM(CAST(traffic AS INT64)) AS traffic_2017
FROM
  data.source
WHERE
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = 2017
GROUP BY month)
USING(month)
```

Comment: That's great, it worked very well! Thank you!

Two questions, I hope you can help me answer too:

1. How would I be able to dynamically set the date condition, something like this: `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)` too get last years traffic dynamically?

2. If I wanted to do the same thing but break it down by day, whats the best way to approach this, is it by doing day-of-the-year, from 1-365?

Thank you for your help, if you can help answer these too that would be really helpful.

Comment: 1. EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))

Comment: 2. second one question is quite difficult because it will generates lots of columns. I would suggest use python/shell to auto-generate sql query using `IF-ELSE / CASE WHEN statement with GROUP BY` technique

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and provides less verbose and easier to read and maintain and extend with more columns version

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT month, 
  SUM(IF(year = 2016, value, 0)) traffic_2016,
  SUM(IF(year = 2017, value, 0)) traffic_2017,
  SUM(IF(year = 2018, value, 0)) traffic_2018,
  SUM(IF(year = 2019, value, 0)) traffic_2019
FROM `project.data.source`, 
UNNEST([STRUCT(
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `date`) AS month, 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `date`) AS year, 
  CAST(traffic AS INT64) AS value
)]) 
GROUP BY month
```